# Perform operation on each item in a list against every other item in the list with exclusions

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of data with no duplicates. For this example I'll say that my list is

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
```

I want to perform my operation on each item in the list against every other item in the list except where I already performed my operation on them (A-B and B-A) or if they are the same (A-A).

EG.

```
A against B
A against C
A against D
B against C
B against D
C against D
```

Now this is fairly simple to do but my list is very large and this process can be quite time consuming. Also with the data I have I don't need to run the operation on matching data or if the operation has already been run

EG.

```
A against A - Skip
A against B - Good
A against C - Good
A against D - Good
B against A - Skip (we already did A against B)
B against B - Skip
B against C - Good
B against D - Good
C against A - Skip
```

and so on.

What I have been looking for (and I don't even know if it exists) is an easy method I can use to do this rather than firing off two loops and doing my operation and saving the results to compare against later.

Looping through the list is `O(n*n)` but as I don't need to compare over half of the results this is a waste of time as I know that I only need to check `O(n*(n/2))`

The code I'm currently using is as follows

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);
List<string> listResult = new List<string>();

list2.Reverse();

int i = 0;
foreach (var a in list1)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (list2.Count / 2); j++)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Looped {0} times", i);

        // Don't run against ourself
        if (a == list2[j])
            continue;

        if (listResult.Count(x => (x == a + list2[j]) || (x == list2[j] + a)) == 0)
        {
            listResult.Add(a + list2[j]);

            // Perform some operation here
            // operation(a, list2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine (I would need to adjust the list2.Count / 2 part to account for an odd numbered list).

Is there a better way to do this? A LINQ extension method I've missed? My problem is I don't really know what to Google for.

I wondered if there was a method that would return the list just containing the items I wanted which I would then loop through and perform my operation. Maybe something using `.SelectMany()`

Comment: Are all the items in your list unique?  i.e. Could your list ever be `A B A C D`?

Comment: are there any duplicates in `list1` ?

Comment: (BTW - The above code skips operation on A and B.)

Comment: There would be no duplicates in the list ever

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each entry in the list, match that up to all entries that come after it in the list, since the items before will already have been matched.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

for( int i = 0; i < list1.Count - 1; i++ )
    for( int j = i + 1; j < list1.Count; j++ )
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} against {1}", list1[i], list1[j] );
```

Edit: As for your second question, how about something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<U> Combinations<T, U>( this IEnumerable<T> list,
                                                     Func<T, T, U> combinator )
    {
        var temp = list.ToArray();
        for( int i = 0; i < temp.Length - 1; i++ )
            for( int j = i + 1; j < temp.Length; j++ )
                yield return combinator( temp[i], temp[j] );
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var res = list1.Combinations( ( a, b ) => string.Format( "{0} against {1}", a, b ) );
```

If you can live with it supporting just `IList` instead of any `IEnumerable`, you could skip the `ToArray` call completely.

Comment: I like this approach for the fact that it is the cleanest, and fastest. ***AND*** uses no additional memory. Which means that it will not hit a `Stack Overflow` exception with *extremely* large `List`s, as the others would.

Answer (score 5):

Just run each element against all elements proceeding it in the list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++) {
        //Run list[i] against list[j]
    }
}
```

This ensures that no element will be run against itself or any element it has already been run against.

Answer (score 1):

Here we loop through all items in cascaded foreach loops. We only add the item if it's not already there or if both are the same, eg. "AA".

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string a in list1)
    foreach (string b in list1)
        if (!result.Contains(b + a) && a != b) result.Add(a + b);
```

Comment: Why, why people believe LINQ is the universal answer to every problem?

Comment: @OndrejTucny It's a great hammer.

Comment: Rolled back to original "LINQ attempt" answer. Completely different solutions shall be posted as separate answers, not edits.

Comment: The answer wasn't "completely" different. I just noticed how `.ForEach` doesn't really make sense like this so I changed it to a casual foreach statement. Please don't rollback again.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Chris answer yet if you need to write out skipped operations it can be easly turn into:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List<string> listResult = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < list1.Count; k++)
    {
        if (k <= i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} against {1} - Skip", list1[i], list1[k]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} against {1} - Good", list1[i], list1[k]);
            listResult.Add(list1[i] + list1[k]);
        }
    }
}
```